# printing a 64bit value in C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, 32bit-64bit

I am using ubuntu x86_64 machine and trying to set the bit position corresponding to the character in string.

Character can a-z or A-Z, so I have kept a 64 bit vector.

```
long unsigned int vector = 0x0;
char *getunqchar(char a[]) {
    char str[30];
    int i;
    long unsigned int t, test = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(a) - 1; i++) {
        t = (long unsigned int)(a[i]) - 65;
        printf("t is %ld", t);
        test = (long unsigned int)(1 << t);
        vector = (vector ) | test;

        printf("vec is %ld %ld \n", (long unsigned int)vector, (long unsigned int)test);
    }
}

int main() {
    int i = 0;
    char name[30], *temp;
    int cnt[52], t;

    memset(cnt, 0, sizeof(cnt));
    printf("vec is %lx", vector);
    printf("Enter the string name: ");
    fgets(name, sizeof(name), stdin);

    temp = getunqchar(name);
}
```

when I input like below:

```
Enter the string name: mAn
t is 44vec is 4096 4096
t is 0vec is 4097 1
t is 45vec is 12289 8192
```

`t` value is `44`, I expect output as `2^44` but I am getting `2^12`.
`44` is `32 + 12`. It seems to be some issue because of 64 bit. But I am not getting. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You say "in C" in the title, but also tag C++. The languages can be very different and solutions in one may not work in the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`1 << t` is evaluated as `int`, use `1UL << t` to evaluate as `unsigned long`.